# Uncaught exception 'TTransportException' with message 'TSocket read 0 bytes'

Tags: php, scala, thrift

Everything fine on Localhost but on server its showing and error like

```
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'TTransportException' with message 'TSocket read 0 bytes' in /var/www/SH_MVC/library/thrift/transport/TSocket.php:263
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/SH_MVC/library/thrift/transport/TTransport.php(87): TSocket->read(4)
#1 /var/www/SH_MVC/library/thrift/transport/TBufferedTransport.php(109): TTransport->readAll(4)
#2 /var/www/SH_MVC/library/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.php(300): TBufferedTransport->readAll(4)
#3 /var/www/SH_MVC/library/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.php(192): TBinaryProtocol->readI32(NULL)
#4 /var/www/SH_MVC/library/thrift/packages/user_node/User_nodeService.php(460): TBinaryProtocol->readMessageBegin(NULL, 0, 0)
#5 /var/www/SH_MVC/library/thrift/packages/user_node/User_nodeService.php(419): user_node_User_nodeServiceClient->recv_create_article()
#6 /var/www/SH_MVC/application/models/neo4j.php(26): user_node_User_nodeServiceClient->create_article('testing1', '0a6c7824a972eea...', 'checking-neo4j', 'checking neo4j&...', '[{"id":"text-co...', '7" while reading response header from upstream, client: 000.00.0.000
```

i wrote a library on Scala with Neo4j and connected to php on ubuntu OS - same as Localhost(mymachine) and Server - its working perfect and with out any issues, but on live server its throwing an error. i copied the log information above. please help me on this.

Comment: check in your phpinfo if socket support is there for php